# Running a unified X display across two separate video cards

Tags: xorg, xrandr, multi-monitor, intel-graphics, ati

I'm trying to set up a triple-head configuration using an ATI X1300/X1550 (RV515) workstation card (ID 1002:7183) alongside my motherboard's integrated Intel HD 2500 (ID 8086:0152).

Thus far, my efforts have produced an old-style isolated setup, with the ATI card running two displays at `:0.0` and the Intel chipset running the 3rd display at `:0.1`.

I believe this is not a hardware problem, as I've managed to get a Xinerama setup working and subsequently drag an Xterm across all three displays.
However, as my displays are different sizes, the process of dragging the window was sufficiently hilarious that I won't be able to use such a configuration.

I'm looking to configure a unified X setup that presents a single `:0` that spans all three displays.

I'm currently using the `radeon` driver for the ATI card. I've also tried using the `modesetting` driver for both the Intel and ATI GPUs, which actually worked perfectly, DRI and all, but sadly also with separate `:0.0` and `:0.1` screens. :(

<sup>This is on Arch Linux, so Xorg et al are fairly up-to-date.</sup>

Comment: Please provide us the `xorg.conf` you use and the command you use to start X, and involved scripts, if there are any.

Comment: Which ATI driver are you using: proprietary (`fglrx`) or free (`radeon`)?

Comment: **@Bananguin:** How should I include this info? I understand Stack Exchange doesn't like linking to other sites, but I don't want to flood my question full of information.  **@Gilles:** Currently using `radeon`, but if `fglrx` will play nice with the `intel` driver and give me a unified display I'm willing to give it a shot.